# BackgroundDownloader - replace/clear request header

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Seems that [BackgroundDownloader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader) class has only one way to [set headers by method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader#Windows_Networking_BackgroundTransfer_BackgroundDownloader_SetRequestHeader_System_String_System_String_), but it lacks a way to clear/reset the header with new value:

> This method allows the caller to set request headers. This method can be called multiple times for the same header. The values will then be concatenated.

Is it possible to do it somehow?

The problem is that I would like to use one downloader to download several files and some services - for example [Dropbox APIv2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download), requires me to put the item's path as a header. That means that if I want to download next file, I've to create new instance of downloader, what I would like to avoid. Is there a way/other method to bypass the problem?

Comment: What I would suggest is that if the service from where you'll make the download allows several items' path in the request header, call the `SetRequestHeader ` for each item you wanna download. It seems `BackgroundDownloader` doesn't permit what want and it's even sealed so no extension is allow.

Comment: @dcg As for sealed downloader, that's what I'm afraid. As for putting several items - not sure if Dropbox allows that, I can't see any doc/sample that will show that case.